# Spring Security Oauth2 SQL Schema for Postgres?

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I intend to use: `JdbcTokenStore`.

As far as I can tell it uses two tables: `oauth_access_token` and `oauth_refresh_token`

I can reverse engineer the table structure; it isn't quite clear if there are references from one table to the other for which I should create a foreign key or not?

Is there a postgres specific schema somewhere? Or another schema that I can refer to?

Batch, for instance, includes the schemas in their dist. I wonder if Oauth2 could do that also?

Many thanks,
Matt

Comment: hello, i am new in oauth and spring-security. I also want to implement with JDBC, but i am confuse, how many tables are created for Oauth?

Comment: Are these the correct tables? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql - Can someone from the oauth project please comment?

Comment: @MattFriedman: Yes, this is valid schema to references. You should write your own answer to help other people easy to find. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

the schema is checked into git as well:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql

when using postgres you should use `bytea` instead of `LONGVARBINARY`